# Copying folder except for one subfolder in Yeoman

Tags: node.js, yeoman, glob, yeoman-generator

I am working on this Yeoman project, and I am copying some files from a template to my new app directory.

This line is doing the job well:

```
this.fs.copyTpl(this.templatePath(''),
    this.destinationPath(this.project_name_slugified+'/'));
```

Everything comes from the template folder and goes to the root folder of the project.

But when someone adds a flag '--nr' I want to exclude one subfolder that has been copied. So `yo my-gen my_app_name --rf` should copy EVERYTHING unless this subfolder.

I tried the !-glob notation, but it's not working. I did something like as first parameter:

```
[this.templatePath('**'),this.templatePath('!subfolder/subfolder_to_be_excluded')]
```

So second parameter was set to exclude the subfolder that is not necessary

I also tried deleting (`delete` method), but it seems that the file is not available immediately.

It's not working anyway. Any ideas? Promisifying the copyTpl would work?

Answer (score 3):

By calling `this.templatePath('!subfolder/subfolder_to_be_excluded')`, you end up generating a broken path: `/absolute/path/!subfolder/etc`.

Use it without `this.templatePath` given you don't need the absolute path to apply the filtering.

```
this.fs.copyTpl(
    [
        this.templatePath('**'),
        '!subfolder/subfolder_to_be_excluded'
    ],
    this.destinationPath(this.project_name_slugified + '/'),
    templateContext
);
```